# Why does pom.xml have these hints?

Tags: eclipse, maven

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
     resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (execution: default-testResources, phase: process-test-resources)
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
     resources-plugin:2.5:resources (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is M2Eclipse answer:
Most, if not all, such problems were traced back to one of two root causes.

Out-of-workspace resource changes made by Maven plugin triggered unexpected workspace builds. This was very indeterministic. In some cases projects appeared to work fine. In some cases, generated/filtered resources would go missing. And in some cases workspace build would go on forever.

Various JVM and OS resources leaks by Maven plugins was another common cause of problems.

and the solution:
If you are using Eclipse 4.2 and have troubles with mapping and won’t put mess into yours pom.xml create new file lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml configure it in Windows -> Preferences -> Maven -> Lifecycle mapping . (don’t forget press Reload workspace lifecycle mappings metadata after each change of this file!).

If you have multiple Eclipse workspaces and/or work in a team, it is easy to get workspace-level configuration out-of-sync. This is unlikely to cause any confusion for  mappings, but for  and  mappings configuration in pom.xml or maven-plugin is strongly recommended.

Here is example based on eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults_1.2.0.20120903-1050.jar/lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml

link:[enter link description here](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html)